# Why can I not run android emulator on wsl2 on Ubuntu 20.04.2?

Tags: 20.04, windows-10, hp, windows-subsystem-for-linux, android-studio

I am using a HP 470 G8 laptop with an 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz processor and I have recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 within WSL2 on my Windows 10 Professional. After installing Android Studio on Ubuntu, I tried to set Android AVD Manager, but I get this error:

> Your CPU does not support required features VT-x or SVM

Here is an image of my problem:

[image: Virtual Device Configuration]

I have enabled **VT-x** in BIOS but I still get the same error and can not start the Android emulator. I also disabled the **Hyper-V** feature in Windows and restarted the laptop, but still get the same error.

So how can I run the Android Emulator even when the Android Studio system says that my CPU does not support VT-x, which is not the truth?

Comment: It's probably complaining because WSL2 already uses the virtualization support so you may well be looking at a situation that is similar to nested VMs.

Comment: When I enter "sudo kvm-ok" command in the Ubuntu command line I get the message that my CPU does not support KVM (kernel-based Virtual Machine) extensions so I suppose that my CPU is still not enough supported in Canonical's Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: No, you understood nothing from the above comment. The problem isn't the CPU, it's WSL2. It won' t be a problem with a normal Ubuntu installation. The problem is trying to run a VM inside a VM. Why aren't you using Android Studio directly in Windows? If you want to use in Ubuntu then install Ubuntu in dual-boot.

Comment: Yeah, dual boot seems more suitable because nothing works fine over wsl2

Comment: Again no, many or actually most things work fine in WSL2. The problem is users with unrealistic expectations.

Comment: I installed windows 10 and Linux Fedora as dual boot on my laptop and everything works fine.
I noticed that on my linux OS the android studio and the emulator work flawlessly.
I also do not have any problems with sound as I had using the Ubuntu on wsl2.
So I think the dual boot is still better way to run 2 OS on one computer than use wsl2.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you would need Nested Virtualization for this, since you are attempting to run a VM inside another vm.  Nested virtualization is only supported in the latest (currently unreleased) WSL available if you are on Windows Insider.

While I can't guarantee that this will work for Android Studio, at the very least you need to be running Windows 11 Beta or a recent Windows 10 Dev Channel build.  This is not necessarily recommended as a daily driver at this point.

According to the [wsl.conf doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#in-preview-options-1), the `nestedVirtualization` option defaults to `true` in these builds.  You can always try forcing it to `true` by creating a `/etc/wsl.conf` file with:

```
wsl2]
nestedVirtualization = true
```

... although again, it *shouldn't* be necessary.

According to [this doc](https://boxofcables.dev/accelerated-kvm-guests-on-wsl-2/) you may even need to compile your own kernel, but that information is about a year old, so the latest WSL kernels may now include that support as well.